# xhttprequest returns multiple times

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm sending a xhttprequest to retrieve some elements from a XML file. However, it seems to return about 8 times: the first 6 times incomplete, the other 2 it returns all items from the XML. Obviously, I only want it once and complete.

The XML file is found at http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/collection/Zuiderspel?own=1&version=1

The website is found at http://i298619.iris.fhict.nl/zuiderspel/spellen/
As you can see, games are shown multiple times (the game 'Alchemist' should be shown twice as it is, but for example the game '99 Chances' is returned several times in the list).

Check the console to see what I mean.

How could I stop the request from returning multiple times so every game gets just shown once?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (true) {
        myFunction(xhttp);
      }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "../wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Zuiderspel.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

  }


  function myFunction(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
    var x, i, xmlDoc, table, spellen, newDiv, newDivImg, stand, jaar, minspelers, maxspelers, speeltijd;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml.responseText, "application/xml");
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      spellen = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      thumbs = x[i].getElementsByTagName("thumbnail")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      stand = x[i].getElementsByTagName("comment")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      jaar = x[i].getElementsByTagName("yearpublished")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.id = "div" + i;
      newDiv.className = "spelClass";
      newDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + thumbs + ")";
      newDiv.innerHTML = "<b>" + spellen + "</b><br />" + stand + "<br />" + jaar;
      document.getElementById("spellen").appendChild(newDiv);

    }
  }

  loadDoc();

</script>
<div id="spellen">

</div>
```

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the first if statement where theres just 'if (true)'.

This is supposed to be ' if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)' yet this gives me Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Comment: `this gives me Unexpected Token ILLEGAL` .... did you want to write out the whole error, because that looks like just part of an error message to me ... and yes, you do need to check `readyState` and `status` ... or use `.onload` instead

Comment: That is the exact error, nothing more. However, adding the ready state and status seperately (so in 2 different if statements right after each other) fixes it. Seems like Wordpress doesn't like Ampersands.

This causes a new problem though: The XML contains about 145 files, yet only about 20 are returned. Seems like the onreadystatechange doesn't work correctly this way

Comment: The script in your website doesn't have `if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)` but `if (xhttp.readyState == 4 and xhttp.status = 200)`

Comment: Funny how you spotted that as that was just a typo that wasn't there for more than a few seconds!

It has double equal signs at both now. However, as you can see on http://i298619.iris.fhict.nl/zuiderspel/pages-1/ ( the page Im testing it on now), it gives 26 games, twice, and nothing more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readystatechange` event doesn't guarantee that the request is done. It just means that it changed [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState).

What you need to do is to check if `readyState` is `4` (DONE) and then call your function. There are other events that trigger when the request is done, such as [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) or [`loadend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadend).

Comment: I do check it on '4' now. I also no longer have my JS directly in the page editor, but I call it externally to prevent Wordpress giving me the Illegal token error I described in the errors

However, if you look at http://i298619.iris.fhict.nl/zuiderspel/pages-1/ , you can see it gives 16 games twice, instead of 145 games once.

It seems to me that even though I check the readystatechange on 4 and the status on 200, it still executes before finishing. Or something like that..

Comment: You call the function (`loadDoc`) twice that's why it's duplicating stuff. There's also some other error in your script...

Comment: Damn, I totally overlooked that, thanks! Another big thing that caused the errors is the fact that I didn't have a check for if some XML elements were empty, which caused the JavaScript to stop running. It all works fine now, thanks a lot.